# Change Formik picker options based on other value - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, picker

I am trying to change the picker options for `state` based on what the user chooses for `country`. Right now I have 2 arrays that correspond to Canada and US. I am using `props.values.country.map` to map the array into picker items, however I get `undefined is not a function`. When I replace `props.values.country` with either `CA` or `US` the picker items map properly. How can I call the country value so I can change the 2nd picker dynamically

```
  var CA = ['Alberta'];
  var US = [];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          state: '',
          country: '',
        }}
        // Form submission action
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          addData(values);
        }}>
        {(props) => (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
            style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.inner}>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={props.values.country}
                onValueChange={props.handleChange('country')}
                style={styles.input}>
                <Picker.Item label="Canada" value="CA" />
                <Picker.Item label="USA" value="US" />
              </Picker>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={props.values.state}
                onValueChange={props.handleChange('state')}
                style={styles.input}>
                {props.values.country.map((item, index) => {
                  return <Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index} />;
                })}
              </Picker>
              <View style={[{width: '90%', margin: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}]}>
                <Button
                  title="place order"
                  color="maroon"
                  onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                  style={{padding: 3, width: '80%'}}
                />
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue where I want the form values to change based what is passed through props